# Illegal instruction (core dumped) embeded model TensorFlow in Beaglebone

Tags: tensorflow, beagleboneblack

I embeded TensorFlow model in Beagelbone Black successfully. I build model with docker with wheel file in https://github.com/DeftWork/rpi-tensorflow.git. But when I predict model (using librosa to prosess data sound), it is failed with:

> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of the problem you're encountering and of what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Did you build with `-mfma` or something and then run on a CPU without FMA support?  Build with `-march=native`.